# How can I continuously return Firebase docChanges realtime updates result from a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vee-validate

I feel like I'm missing something basic but I have gone through the Firebase documentation and have looked through every relevant SO post I could find.

I have the following function:

```
const checkUsername = username => {
  const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

  fb.usernamesCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    let isValid = querySnapshot.docChanges().every(change => {
      return !(
        (change.type === 'added' && change.doc.id === username) ||
        (change.type === 'removed' && change.doc.id !== username)
      )
    })
    console.log('result 1: ', isValid)
    callback(isValid)
  })
}
```

I am feeding the result of `checkusername` into a custom VeeValidate rule, so it needs to be a boolean value

To that end, I am trying to return the value of `isValid`, which is set based on (in this case) the presence or absence of a username in my `usernamesCollection`  and evaluated anytime a new document is added/removed from the collection.

Since any change to the collection within Firebase will trigger `isValid` to be re-calculated, I can't rely on wrapping it all in a Promise and returning that as that will only execute on input change due to how it works in conjunction with VeeValidate.

The complete code can be seen below:

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate'

const checkUsername = username => {
  const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

  fb.usernamesCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    let isValid = querySnapshot.docChanges().every(change => {
      return !(
        (change.type === 'added' && change.doc.id === username) ||
        (change.type === 'removed' && change.doc.id !== username)
      )
    })
    console.log('result 1: ', isValid)
    callback(isValid)
  })
}

const uniqueUsername = value => {
    const Filter = require('bad-words')
    const filter = new Filter()
    const username = value.toLowerCase().trim()

    let isValid = false

    try {
        if (!filter.isProfane(username)) {
            checkUsername(username, available => {
                console.log('result 2: ', available) //<---Not available outside this scope
            })
        }
        return {
            valid: isValid
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return {
            valid: false
        }
    }
}

Validator.extend(
    'unique_username',
    {
        getMessage: field => `${field} is not available.`,
        validate: uniqueUsername
    },
    {
        immediate: false
    }
)
```

This is most likely an issue with the Firebase call being asynchronous, but I'm not sure how to modify my code to account for this. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you make `checkUsername` return a promise that resolves with `isValid` then you can await that in `uniqueUsername`

```js
const checkUsername = username => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

    fb.usernamesCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      let isValid = querySnapshot.docChanges().every(change => {
        return !(
          (change.type === 'added' && change.doc.id === username) ||
          (change.type === 'removed' && change.doc.id !== username)
        )
      })
      console.log('result: ', isValid)
      resolve(isValid);
    });
  });

}

const uniqueUsername = async value => {
  const Filter = require('bad-words')
  const filter = new Filter()

  const username = value.toLowerCase().trim()
  let isValid = false

  try {
    if (!filter.isProfane(username)) {
      const isValid = await checkUsername(username) // <--- this is where I want the value returned to
    }
    return {
      valid: isValid
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return {
      valid: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was one of the original solutions I tried by using a callback, however I'm not sure how the `uniqueUsername` function can return the `isValid` value so that it validates correctly due to the fact that I'm still within the scope of the callback function.

Comment: @RedArmy I've modified my answer so that you can get the returned value in `uniqueUsername`. Note that `uniqueUsername` must be asynchronous in order to return a value from an asynchronous process.

Comment: Wrapping it in a promise was another thing I had tried, the problem is as I mentioned in my post that the way the Firebase `docChanges()` method works is that it gets fired on any document change in the collection you are listening to. Due to that, wrapping the entire `onSnapShot` call will only work when you type something and the whole function is re-run as opposed to when a document change occurs and that internal method is fired. I'm starting to think there's no easy way to do this with VeeValidate and I should just do a simple non-real time Firebase get().

Comment: @RedArmy You want to rerun `uniqueUsername` on doc change?

Comment: Correct, anytime a document change is picked up by the listener, I want the rule to be re-evaluated to see if the username is still available. This, however, goes against the flow of how VeeValidate works since rules are evaluated based on input change.

Comment: Yea, if you can't force this VeeValidate to re-evaluate, I don't think you're gonna find a way around it.

Comment: @RedArmy strolling through my answer history and saw this...
If what was needed was to get VeeValidate to re-evaluate, which it only does on input change, you could manually trigger the change event on the validated input element, on doc change.